# Measuring BLDC motor resistance during operation

Tags: motor, resistance, brushless-dc-motor, sensing

### Question

Is it possible to sense the resistance of a hobby BLDC motor **during operation?**

I should clarify that I'm trying to quantify how resistance increases due to thermal effects under load. Thus, I don't need an absolute reading on resistance. I just need an estimate of resistance change between two points in time, such as when motor starts and when it reaches steady-state temperature.

### Current guess

I know the motor kt, and I can measure the applied DC voltage (V), DC current (I), rotational speed (\$\omega\$). Assuming I:

1. Ignore motor inductance since its typically orders of magnitude smaller than R
2. Lump drops across the motor controller into some constant (c)

Then I can use the governing equation of DC motors as follows:

$$
V = IR + k_t \omega + c
$$
$$
V = IR + E + c
$$
$$
R = (V-E - c)/I
$$
$$
R = (V-E)/I - c
$$

Now we take these measurements at two points in time: 1 and 2. The constant will drop out and we can get a rough estimate of the change in resistance.
$$
\Delta R = R_2 - R_1
$$

$$
\Delta R = (\frac{(V_2-E_2)-c}{I_2}) - (\frac{(V_1-E_1)-c}{I_1})
$$

$$
\Delta R = (\frac{(V_2-E_2)}{I_2} -c) - (\frac{(V_1-E_1)}{I_1} -c)
$$

$$
\Delta R = (\frac{(V_2-E_2)}{I_2}) -c - (\frac{(V_1-E_1)}{I_1}) + c
$$

$$
\Delta R = (\frac{(V_2-E_2)}{I_2}) - (\frac{(V_1-E_1)}{I_1})
$$

**Are my assumptions valid? Is there a better, less hand-wavey approach?**

Comment: The physical resistance of the wire will not change (apart from temperature effects) but the impedance will. What are you wanting to determine?

Comment: Neglecting (L) is one heck of an assumption too.

Comment: You're reshaping the equation incorrectly. Take another look at how `c` got out of those brackets.

Comment: @Kartman Actually I'd like to sense the change in resistance *because* of thermal effects. I should have noted that.

Comment: @user_1818839 How should I treat it then? L isn't published for any hobby motor, and I can't measure di/dt of the waveform.

Comment: @SimSon You're saying. c/I will be different at each moment in time, correct?

Comment: I say that `(V-E-c)/I` does *not* equal `(V-E)/I-c` and therefore `c` must still be in your last equation.

Comment: @SimSon Yes, I see. Hmmm, any suggestions for my broader question then?

Comment: Hinestly, I don't understand the point of your question. Measure U and I at any time and you can calculate the impedance at that time. I'd don't understand what you want to achieve with that delta R.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132743/discussion-between-techsultan-and-sim-son).